# Parse Objective-C printf Format Strings?

Tags: objective-c, c, printf

I want to get the ranges of members within an `NSString` built with `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`. What is the best way to parse the objective-c format string? I can't just use a C format string parser because of `%@`. I also need to make sure it supports format orderings: `%1$d`, `%2$@`, etc.

For example, with the string built with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"foo %2$@ bar %1$@", @"Heath", @"Borders"]`, I would ideally like the following `NSArray`: `@[NSMakeRange(15, 5), NSMakeRange(4, 6)]`. The first array object corresponds to the first data element in the format string, the second array object to the second data element, etc.

In this case, the API would look something like `+ (NSString *) stringWithFormatRanges:(NSArray **)outFormatRanges withFormat:(NSString *)format, ... NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);` It would return an `NSString` just like `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, but it would also return an `NSArray` with `NSRange`s of each format data element.

**-- EDIT --**

Given that this question is 3 years old, I'd be happy with a C-only implementation at this point.

Comment: Parsing how, what is your exact requirement...please explain.

Comment: What do you mean by "ranges of members?" Are you saying you want to parse for substrings such as "%@", "%1$d" and "%2$@"?

Comment: I would think you'd first extract the individual format items, perhaps with REs, then write code to inspect them and classify them.

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if your requirements were more clear. What does the signature of the function/method you need to write look like?

Comment: I hope I've answered your questions adequately. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In spite of it not being documented, does C `printf()`'s [`%n` specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) work as expected in Objective-C? If so this is about as simple as writing a wrapper around `stringWithFormat` that injects `%n` immediately before and after the other specifiers, invokes the formatter, and then post-processes the byte-counts into whichever form you need.

Comment: Iwillnotexist Idonotexist, That's super handy! I didn't know about `%n`! However, "writing a wrapper around `stringWithFormat` that injects `%n` immediately before and after the other specifiers" doesn't seem at all simple. The specifier grammar is very complicated! :(

Comment: @HeathBorders Well, I'm hedging a bit my bets: I don't know for a fact that `%n` works with `stringWithFormat`, and "about as simple" only establishes an upper bound on complexity. But I do think that wrapping specifiers with `%n` would probably be a _touch_ easier than implementing one's own formatted printer or doing crazy analyses on the printed string post facto. Also, isn't parsing the specs as easy as scanning for unescaped `%`'s, then scanning for the next "terminating" letter of a spec, one out of `@diuoxXeEfFgGaAcspn`? In-between you're allowed other characters, but AFAIK not those.

Comment: If it is that easy, then yes, that's ideal. Even if `steingWithFormat:` doesn't support it, I'm fine with doing `fprintf` to `/dev/null` or something. I figured that different C implementations might have different allowable terminating characters, which might complicate things.

Comment: Implementations of printf typically do not create an AST for the formatting strings. They kinda just wing it.

Comment: @HeathBorders Well, the C standard's description of [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) uses a disjoint set of characters for the conversion specifiers and what comes in-between (_flag, field width, precision, length modifier_). What bothers me is that the `%@` conversion specifier might not be supported by plain `printf()`, but `%n` might not be supported by `stringWithFormat`.

Answer (score 5):

I looked into this a few years ago. If I understand your question, there's no easy way to get the AST from a format string for either C or Cocoa format strings.

I wrote NSXMLElement+elementWithXMLFormat which allowed unescaped insertion of NSXMLElements into a format string with a special `%%%@` format code, which required extending Cocoa's format. My technique may be helpful to you:

https://github.com/rentzsch/nsxmlelement-elementwithxmlformat/blob/937b54b2a830a8fbbd72d6bc5e48bafd495ddcbd/NSXMLElement%2BelementWithXMLFormat.m#L41

I extract and NUL-delimit just the format codes, run it through traditionally and then reassemble.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at this tonight. it does look promising.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a parser for those in Swift (so that I can detect those placeholders in `Localizable.strings` and extract which types were expected to be given when calling `stringWithFormat:` with those strings) for my tool [SwiftGen](https://github.com/AliSoftware/SwiftGen/)

You can see the part of the code doing the parsing [there on my GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen/blob/b1e1b06c110c509ebdb554ce3321dc0678bbe6fb/Sources/SwiftGenKit/Parsers/Strings/PlaceholderType.swift#L44-L120).

- Sure, it's in Swift and not Objective-C but I guess it's easily translatable to ObjC, as long as you keep the logic of the algorithm.
- My code doesn't return the ranges either as output of those functions — only the types — but the code in the `typesFromFormatString` functions definitely has access to the ranges of those placeholders and could totally return them in addition to the detected type (that's an easy change, I just didn't need those ranges so I didn't include them in the return type)

*(Once you have the ranges for the placeholders like `%d` or `%2$@`, it'll be easy to deduce the ranges for the string parameters : the first range will have the same `.location` as the 1st placeholder but the length of the replaced value, the 2nd range will have the `.location` of the 2nd placeholder + (firstValue.length-firstRange.length) to take the offset into account, etc)*

HTH.