# What exactly does '%Id' mean? (uppercase I, lowercase d)

Tags: c, glibc

I'm asking about `%Id`, not `%ld`.

Can anyone please explain to me what does "I" exactly do:

> `I`      For decimal integer conversion (`i`, `d`, `u`) the output uses the
>   locale's alternative output digits, if any.  For
>             example, since glibc 2.2.3 this will give Arabic-Indic digits in the Persian (`"fa_IR"`) locale.

As an example:

```
printf("%Id",1);
```

In other words what is the difference between `%d` and `%Id` ?

can anyone please explain it with simple words and simple example stating the difference ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: why are you always downvoting my questions I am trying to understand we don't have the same brain and the way of thinking !

Comment: You've pasted in an explanation of exactly what `I` does. If you don't understand that then please describe specifically which part of that explanation you don't understand so that someone can address your specific gap.

Comment: I have edited my question @Olaf thanks for clarifying !

Comment: @RondinoManou _"why are you always downvoting my questions"_ Read about reasons [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Comment: @RondinoManou: If you address me, use the proper markdown tags! Take the [tour]. Re your complain: I'm apparently not the only. Did it come into your mind it might be your questions?

Comment: @user3386109: I don't think so ... It is a glibc-specific flag (no conversion modifier/specifier).

Comment: Your question is not clearer. What other than what the quotation already strates do you expect? Maybe you need to do some research about locales to understand it? (no offence!)

Comment: I feel like my question will be deleted soon can anyone please give at least a quick answer explaining it with simple words and in what did I misunderstand the glibc-specific flag !

Comment: @user3386109: And I do repeat: Please read the glibc `printf` manpage and you will see!

Comment: It is okay @Olaf I am used to that tense !

Comment: @Olaf Hmm, that's bad news for [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201612/parse-objective-c-printf-format-strings).

Comment: @user3386109: I don't get what you mean. He is up for some ObjC stuff, not explicitly `printf`. According to the C standard illegal "tokens" in the format string are UB, thus the implementaion is free to use it for its own purposes. I'm a bit ambivalent about this, but then glibc addresses a relevant issue, there are more locale-issues than in the western languages.

Comment: what do you mean by `research about locales` @Olaf. To be honest it is the first time I hear such term in C !

Comment: @RondinoManou: Please use the grey matter in your head:-)

Comment: In simplistic terms the locale determines country specific settings. In this case `I` will change how numbers are printed out based on the locale/country setting (not every country uses the same numeral system).

Comment: @kaylum so if I well understood I will almost never need it while programming. thanks !

Comment: @RondinoManou: And you can't even google for `glibc locales`? Just a well meant (honestly!) note: you will not get far in programming (especially C) if you don't start putting the pieces together yourself.

Comment: Well, you will need it if you ever write any code to be run not only in the US and on EN_US locale computers!

Comment: @RondinoManou: kaylum gave you a good one. %Id is specific in glibc, for some countries which display numbers differently than %d does.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: That is not `%ld`, but `%Id`! And no, that is not the point. `%d` is fine for the **standard** format of the locale. (Notice the word "alternative" in the quotation)

Comment: I will do my best next time but since I don't even know about that I cannot figure out what I am searching exactly anyway thanks guys !

Comment: I did not say it would be easy. It is more of a general attitude.

Comment: @Olaf: I wrote %Id (capital eye dee). This iPad has no backticks, so I can not make them fixed width font, sorry.

Comment: Do I need to delete my question ?

Comment: @Rondino: you could have tried to google the meaning of the words you did not know (like "locale") in the description. Help yourself and people will be glad to help you if you still have the occasional problem.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I will try promise but I am still a beginner !

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Hmm, maybe you need a better keyboard-app then ;-)

Comment: @RondinoManou: Ignorantia legis non excusat ... (That be my last comment on that subject:-).

Comment: @Rondino: Everyone was a beginner once, me too. But I always tried very hard to find a solution by myself. There was no Stack Overflow, no Internet, etc. There was no one I could ask. Just some tips from a few magazines about programming. And books. I used to read a lot. But you can use Google, etc. That's heaven. And simply don't give up if you don't immediately find what you want.

Comment: you lived in the Golden age you are lucky ! @RudyVelthuis

Comment: @Rondino: You live in the golden age. You have many more sources of information at yor disposal. **Use them!** I started programming in the stone age.

Comment: Trust me I still prefer your age ! You grow up with the internet together ! that's why ! @RudyVelthuis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` format option `I` is a glibC extension to select a locale representation for numbers.  It is not defined by the C Standard and should not be used in portable code.

If the locale is properly selected and supported by your C library, calling `printf("%Id", 1);` might produce a string encoding the Unicode code point U+0661 `١` that is the representation of the digit one in arabic.

See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0661/index.htm

Conversely, `printf("%d", 1);` always prints `1`, the western representation of number one.

To make matters even more confusing, `1` is called an *arabic numeral*, as opposed to *roman numeral* `I`... unrelated to the `I` in `%Id`.